# Diagnosing Failed Web Requests Safari

Tags: network, safari, console

I am having some trouble with Safari not loading any sites. When I enter a URL the site appears to load forever without making progress. There are no errors, and this state will continue until I forcibly stop it. I grabbed some logs from Console, but I can't see any apparent errors, although it looks to me like Webkit might be resetting the connection to "Google.com"

I am using a kernel extension which rebinds Safari sockets so that the traffic goes out the physical interface rather than the tunnel...aka a "split tunnel". This kernel extension works perfectly for all apps except Safari. I am trying to understand why it does not work with Safari.

Safari will load HTTP without a problem, but when I try to navigate to a site employing HTTPS, such as Google, it will appear as if the site is loading forever without making any progress. Wireshark shows my local machine sending TCP reset requests to Google after attempting to establish the handshake. Sometimes it looks like the handshake completes and sometimes not.

I took some logs from Console which may show the handshake resetting, but I'm having a hard time understanding them.

Can anyone tell me what is going on in these logs, or point me to some resources which will help explain them?

Here are the [logs](https://pastebin.com/3PK17MT0).